# React + TailwindCSS. Overflow works incorrect for modal window

Tags: css, reactjs, modal-dialog, position, tailwind-css

I have a component that is responsible for rendering a modal window, and I can't attach it's content on top of the modal window.

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react'
import cx from 'classnames'

export interface ModalProps {
  className?: string 
  children: ReactNode
  visible: boolean
  onClose: () => void
}

const Modal = ({ className, children, visible, onClose }: ModalProps) => {
  const handleOnCloseModal = () => {
    onClose()
  }

  if (!visible) return null

  return (
    <div
      className={cx(
        'fixed',
        'flex',
        'justify-center',
        'items-start',
        'p-10',
        'inset-0',
        'bg-black',
        'bg-opacity-30',
        'backdrop-blur-sm',
      )}
      onClick={handleOnCloseModal}
    >
      <div
        className={cx(
          className,
          'relative',
          'flex',
          'flex-col',
          'items-start',
          'justify-center',
          'w-6/12',
          'h-3/4',
          'rounded',
          'bg-white',
          'overflow-x-hidden',
          'overflow-y-scroll'
        )}
        onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
      >
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Modal
```

If I make fixed modal size (f.e. 300px), some of the content hidden from above (see the screenshot)

[Modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6uZF.png)

It must be like this, but I want the size of the modal window not to go beyond the page

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y82go.png)

Comment: i think the problem is the second div justify-center. its made your children come to center and push 2 way out.

Comment: try to replace it with justify-start

Comment: Try to replace `h-3/4` to `h-full` in the second div